# Define a function remotely using PROC FCMP in SAS

Tags: sas

I've just learned **PROC FCMP** from this page:

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003181727.htm

The function works fine locally, so I wonder if I can use this proc remotely. In my point of view, as long as I change the output library for this function, it could be used in remote server. Here's my code:

```
proc fcmp outlib=rwork.funcs.trial;
   function study_day2(intervention_date, event_date);
      n = event_date - intervention_date;
         if n >= 0 then
            n = n + 1;
         return (n);
   endsub;
options cmplib=rwork.funcs;
run;

rsubmit;
data _null_;
   start = '15Feb2008'd;
   today = '27Mar2008'd;
   sd = study_day2(start, today);
   put sd=;
run;
endrsubmit;
```

For the 1st section, I get a notice that the function has been saved in the RWORK library:

> NOTE: Function study_day2 saved to rwork.funcs.trial.

However after running the 2nd section, I get this error:

> ERROR 68-185: The function STUDY_DAY2 is unknown, or cannot be
>   accessed.

Is there a way to fix this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to program this way (compile the function on your local machine and run it remotely), and you have a machine connected over SAS/CONNECT that is the same operating system and bitness (64/32 bit) as your local machine, you need to run `options cmplib=rwork.funcs;` in your rsubmit (except you likely need to change it, assuming `rwork` refers to your remote work directory, to `options cmplib=work.funcs;`).

```
rsubmit;
 options cmplib=work.funcs;
 data _null_;
    start = '15Feb2008'd;
    today = '27Mar2008'd;
    sd = study_day2(start, today);
    put sd=;
 run;
endrsubmit;
```

That option isn't for `proc fcmp`, as you seem to think based on where you located it.  It is telling SAS where to look when *using* the function.  (The `outlib` option in `proc fcmp` is what is needed to store it there.)

If your remote server is a different OS or bitness than your local machine, you can't do this, and would need to put the entire section of code in the `rsubmit`.

Comment: Thanks Joe for the answer (esp. the explanation for OPTIONS CMPLIB). I revised the code as you suggested, but still get the same error. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Nip Is the remote computer the same operating system and bitness as your local PC?

Comment: Both are Windows but I need to check the bitness.

Comment: I will add that I've never had a situation where I did have the possibility to rsubmit from one windows box to another, so I don't know if (For example) you can do the same from a desktop to a server -it's possible you can't, and have to `rsubmit` the entire bit.